# How does the Linux command "mount -a" work?

Tags: linux, mount, partition, fstab

After adding a new mount point in `/etc/fstab`, we usually execute `mount -a` to reflect the change (if we want to bypass reboot), and `df -kh` output shows the new mount point.

How does `mount -a` work/impact already mounted partitions, which have reference to the `/etc/fstab` file?  Does it umount and then mount those partitions, or just ignore them since they are already mounted?

Comment: Why do you usually run `mount -a` instead of just `mount <thenewmountpoint>`?

Answer (score 23):

It skips ones already mounted.

https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/sys-utils/mount.c#L185-L193

```c
while (mnt_context_next_mount(cxt, itr, &fs, &mntrc, &ignored) == 0) {

    const char *tgt = mnt_fs_get_target(fs);

    if (ignored) {
        if (mnt_context_is_verbose(cxt))
            printf(ignored == 1 ? _("%-25s: ignored\n") :
                          _("%-25s: already mounted\n"),
                   tgt);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It will ignore already mounted partitions.

In the same time, you can do a `mount -o remount /dev/xxx` on a partition already mounted, this won't cause any problem even if users are using this partition

Answer (score 1):

The better option would be mount the new file system manually and add the new file system entry in the /etc/fstab to make sure this f/s get mounted on every reboot.

As mentioned above "mount -a" will ignore the already mounted file systems and mount only the file system which was not mounted yet (new file system).

Hope this will helps.

Comment: I prefer "mount -a" option for a new file system rather than manually mount it. In this way, I'm also verifying if /etc/fstab entry is correct.